# How to get the remaining time of pending UNNotificationRequest?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, unnotificationrequest, unnotificationtrigger

So far, after adding a `UNNotificationRequest` to the `UNUserNotificationCenter` that contains `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` (Here is the code that I implemented):

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    if granted {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        center.delegate = self
        content.title = "title"
        content.body = "body"
        
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10.0, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request)
    }
}
```

It works -fine- as it should, but what I need is to access the remaining time for firing the request trigger.

For clarity, in my code snippet, I declared:

`let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10.0, repeats: false)`

So, if I wait **6** seconds (starting from executing the above code snippet), the remaining time should be **4** seconds.

Also, I tried to fetch the pending requests to check their triggers, as follows:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { requests in
     for request in requests {
         print(request.trigger)
     }
})
```

but couldn't find the desired property in [UNNotificationTrigger](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationtrigger).

The question might be is there even a way to access it? and if it's not, what about a logical workaround to achieve it?

Comment: you can get the nextTriggerDate and get the date timeIntervalSinceNow property`print(request.trigger.nextTriggerDate() ?? "nil")`

Comment: @LeoDabus Could you elaborate? what if there is no next trigger? i.e what if it only one?

Comment: next trigger only returns the NEXT trigger date. It will never return more than one

Comment: try `print(request.trigger.nextTriggerDate()?.timeIntervalSinceNow ?? "")`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks alot, it actually works! but the problem is after terminating the app and relaunch it again, it seems that the notification will reset, i.e, the remaining time will be reseted. Any idea?

Comment: Have you found any solution @AhmadF

Answer (score 4):

I get the time interval value from pending UNNotificationRequest 
**Swift4 code**

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: {requests -> () in
for request in requests {
    let localTrigger = request.trigger  as! UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
    localTimeInterval = localTrigger.timeInterval
    print (localTimeInterval)
}})
```